# How to store lines from a textfile to a list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a C# program in Visual Studio that will read a textfile and add the lines to a list.
The textfile contains lines of people's name and their age.

```
  Name: Amy
  Age: 30
  Name: Bob
  Age: 25
  ....
```

The textfile is sent to the List function as a parameter.

In the List function, I want to read each line from the textfile and add it to the list (info1).

I have written a code. But there are building errors when I run the code.

There is a error in the line

```
    info1.Add(line.ToString());
```

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Class1
{

    public void Main()
    {
        List<Info> info1 = Load(@"filename.txt");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}


public List<Info> Load(string file)
    {
        List<Info> info1 = new List<Info>();

        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                info1.Add(line.ToString());                  

            }
        }
        return info1;
    }



public class Info
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }

    public Info(string name, string age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;

    }

}
```

}

I'm not sure of the mistake I have made. Is there an error in my code?

Edit: I'm not sure how to rectify the code to ensure that I can add to the list. How can I rectify the code?

Comment: You try to add Type string where it expects Type  Info

Comment: Since `info1` is a `List<Info> info1` you can't add `string` via `info1.Add(line.ToString());`

Comment: Thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to create one `Info` object out of each couple of lines:

```
public static List<Info> Load(string file)
{
    List<Info> results = new List<Info>();

    string name = null;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
    {
        bool isName = false;
        string age = null;
        if (line.Contains("Name:"))
        {
            name = null;
            isName = true;
        }

        string value = line.Split(':')[1];

        if (isName)
            name = value;
        else
            age = value;

        if (!isName)
        {
            results.Add(new Info(name, age));
            name = null;
        }

    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.ToString()` [method returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) `string`, but you're trying to add it to a list of `Info`. That's why your code does not compile.

You need to read two lines (first is name info, the second one is an age info), [create a new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx) `Info` instance and [store it in the list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add in a `List<Info>` a `string` object.
As it is a type violation, the compiler probably give you a casting error

Answer (score 0):

List is of type `Info` but code is trying to add `string`, which is causing an exception.

This should fix your problem, solution uses `Linq`.

```
public List<Info> Load(string file)
{
    List<Info> info1 = new List<Info>(); 
    var contents = File.ReadLines(file)
        .Select(x=> new {item=x, index=i})
        .GroupBy(x=> x.index/2)
        .Select(x=> new Info() 
         {
             Name = x.First().item.Split(':')[1],    // Name
             Age = x.Last().item.Split(':')[1]      // Age
         }
        .ToList();

    info1.AddRange(content);

    return info1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Info> info1 = new List<Info>();
```

`info1` is a `List<Info>`, but you add a `string` to the list:

`info1.Add(line.ToString());`

You should create a new `Info` object and add it to `info1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"filename.txt");
List<Info> infos = new List<Info>();
foreach(var line in lines)
{   
    string name = "";
    string age = "";
    if(line.StartsWith("Name:"))
    {
        name = line.Replace("Name: ", "");      
    }
    else if(line.StartsWith("Age:"))
    {
        age = line.Replace("Age: ", "");
    }
    Info info = new Info(name, age);
    infos.Add(info);
}
```

Comment: I think it will add one row of name without settnig age and one row with age without setting name. If you put the info creation and addition in else block then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new instance of Info class to add Info list because your list type is "Info" and you are trying to add "string"

```
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        string line;// for Name
        string line2;//for Age

        while ((line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            line2= rdr.ReadLine();
            info1.Add(new Info(line,line2));                  

        }
    }
    return info1;
}
```